# NEXT.JS: Can't connect to mongoDB Database using getInitialProps

Tags: node.js, mongodb, next.js

I'm trying to connect to my sample mongoDB collection using getInitialProps inside my `_app.js` but I'm having this issue of `Module not found: Can't resolve 'dns'`

`_app.js`

```
import { connectToDatabase } from '../middlewares/mongodb';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps, prop }) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  );
}

MyApp.getInitialProps = async (appContext) => {
  const { db } = await connectToDatabase();
  const data = await db
    .collection('listingsAndReviews')
    .find({})
    .limit(10)
    .toArray();

  const prop = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
  return { ...prop };
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getInitialProps` runs on the server during initial page load and on the client during client navigations. As such `getInitialProps` should contain isomorphic code - code able to run in both server and client environments.

In your case you have code that requires a Node.js environment (server), and as such will fail when running on the browser.

---

A possible solution is to move your database fetching logic to an API route.

```js
// pages/api/listings

export const fetchDbData = async () => {
    const { db } = await connectToDatabase();
    const data = await db
        .collection('listingsAndReviews')
        .find({})
        .limit(10)
        .toArray();
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
}

export default async (req, res) => {
    const data = await fetchDbData()
    res.status(200).json(data)
}
```

In your `getInitialProps` you can then call the `fetchDbData` logic directly when it's running on the server, or make an API call when it's running on the client.

```js
import { fetchDbData } from './api/listings';

MyApp.getInitialProps = async (appContext) => {
    let prop;

    if (appContext.ctx.req) { // Checks if running on server
        prop = await fetchDbData(); // Call logic directly on the server
    } else {
        const res = await fetch('/api/listings'); // Make API call on the client
        prop = await res.json();
    }

    return { ...prop };
};
```

This ensures your database fetching logic will always run in the server environment.

Comment: The problem also is on my MongoDB connection inside my middleware folder. If I import the connection in the root file inside the pages folder, it returns DNS error.

Comment: You only need to import it in your API route.

Comment: Sorry, i overlook it. but it's working now! Thanks again!

Comment: Have you updated to version 10.2? And if so, is it still working? Also, have you confirmed that this "db query" is running on every pageload/page refresh, in other words, refresh page, fires...refresh again, fires? OR does it only fire/run during build time of the whole application?

Comment: Usually, the call to the database would occur on each page request/transition as `getInitialProps` runs during that time. However, it will run at build time only if your pages are statically generated with `getStaticProps` - see  [_app.getInitialProps is not called on every request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71587308/app-getinitialprops-is-not-called-on-every-request).

Comment: this helped me so much, simple elegant, perfect! thanks!