# _app.getInitialProps is not called on every request

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am setting the theme based on the hostname. Everything works in dev mode, but I just ran `npm run build` and I see that `getInitialProps` gets called during build time. I cannot find any information on when `_app`'s `getInitialProps` gets called.

I built the whole app thinking `_app`'s `getInitialProps` gets called on every request. Does `getInitialProps` not get called from every request (initial page load and route changes)?

This is `_app.tsx`:

```
MyApp.getInitialProps = async (appContext: AppContext) => {
  
  const selectedBusinessWhitelabelKey = getWhitelabelKeyFromHostname(appContext.ctx.req?.headers.host || '');
  
  const selectedBusinessWhitelabelValues = whitelabel[selectedBusinessWhitelabelKey];
  return {
    ...appProps,
    selectedBusinessWhitelabelValues,
    themeObj: allThemes[selectedBusinessWhitelabelKey],
  };
};
```

The component:

```
function MyApp(props: AppProps & { emotionCache: EmotionCache; [key: string]: any }) {
  const { Component, emotionCache = clientSideEmotionCache, pageProps, themeObj, selectedBusinessWhitelabelValues } = props;
  const [theme] = useState(createTheme(themeObj));

  return (
    <CacheProvider value={emotionCache}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <Layout selectedBusinessWhitelabelValues={selectedBusinessWhitelabelValues}>
          <Component {...pageProps} selectedBusinessWhitelabelValues={selectedBusinessWhitelabelValues} />
        </Layout>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </CacheProvider>
  );
}
```

If this is not the right way to set theme based on the `hostname` (the request domain), what else can I do?

Comment: Where does `appProps` inside `MyApp.getInitialProps` come from?

Comment: How are you verifying that `getInitialProps` gets called? `getInitialProps` will get called on every request to the page.

Comment: @juliomalves I added console.log and checked. It gets called at build time only with npm run build. Not after npm run start

Comment: Do your pages use `getStaticProps`?

Comment: @juliomalves yes.  I use it for i18n - https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next

Comment: That's why it only runs at build time. For pages with `getStaticProps` the `_app`'s `getInitialProps` only gets called at build time. If you want it to run on every request, you either need to not use any data fetching method or use `getServerSideProps` in the page.

Comment: @juliomalves so I shouldn't use getStaticProps in any pages at all?

Comment: If you want `getInitialProps` to run on every request on every page, then yeah.

Comment: @juliomalves thanks, you can write this as answer and I will accept

Comment: @juliomalves one more question. does `useState` get called on server side while rendering. I did `console.log(useState(() => {console.log("usestate called")}))` and see the log in server

Comment: Yes, it will get called while pre-rendering the page on the server.

Comment: @juliomalves only `useState`, not `useEffect` but why? Can you please give me a source to understand this better

Comment: What's inside the `useState` is it's initialization, it's setting the initial value for the state variable. That will run both on the server and on the client. On the other hand, `useEffect` runs when the component gets mounted, that only happens on the client. The official React docs are a good source: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour of `getInitialProps` in `_app` will vary based on the data fetching methods used in your pages:

- For pages that use `getStaticProps`, the `_app`'s `getInitialProps` function only gets called at build time.
- For pages that use `getServerSideProps`, the `_app`'s `getInitialProps` function gets called on every request and will always run on the server.
- For pages that either use `getInitialProps` or do not have any data fetching method, the `_app`'s `getInitialProps` function gets called on every request. For the initial page load `getInitialProps` will run on the server. For subsequents page navigations (using `next/link` or `next/router`) `getInitialProps` will then run on the client.

In your case, you're most likely experiencing the first scenario. If you want `getInitialProps` to run on every request, you either need to not use any data fetching method or use `getServerSideProps` in your pages.

Note that in development mode `getInitialProps` and `getStaticProps` get called on every page load, hence why you were only experiencing it in production mode.